# How are few-nanometer multigate MOSFETs fabricated?

Tags: mosfet, solid-state-devices, manufacturing-process, microfabrication, clean-room

Intel and IMEC came up with multigate MOSFET designs with channels as narrow as new nanometers. Which methods/techniques/machines are used to pattern/fabricate such small features?

[image]([source](http://www.techdesignforums.com/blog/2012/10/11/intel-tsmc-finfet-iedm/))

[image]([source](http://www2.imec.be/be_en/press/imec-news/lateral-nanowires-vlsi.html))

Comment: https://cmi.epfl.ch/metrology/files/Nova600/John_Melngailis/Lecture1.pdf
FIB's or Electron beams are good starting points :)

Comment: FIB and E-Beam, that is nonsense, FIB and Electron beams methods are not used for producing chips they're used for making test-modifications and inversitgations, not for productions.

Answer (score 1):

The way that these structures are fabricated is mentioned in the article. It is basically a "conventional bulk FinFET flow" with an added STI and "a low-complexity ground plane doping". That sounds to me more like a change in recipe than a change in manufacturing methods.

So these structures are made in the same way as most modern chips are made. They **cannot** use something much different as that would make it **very expensive** to implement in the IC manufacturing processes. If IMEC would propose too radical changes, **no manufacturer would use it**.